# How to change the width of bootstrap nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to create a webpage, with bootstrap, using a template for a dashboard online (Creative Tim), where I have a static nav-bar and a sidebar. The sidebar extends all along the page's length. However I would like a fixed nav bar, but whenever I attempt to do this, there is interference between the nav bar and the side bar.

The first image with a static nav-bar looks like: 
[image]

My html code for this bit is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sidebar" data-color="red" data-image="assets/img/sample.jpg">

    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="" class="simple-text">
                Engineering
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="dashboard.html">
                    <i class="pe-7s-graph"></i>
                    <p>Dashboard</p>
                </a>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main-panel">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <p class="navbar-brand">Muhammad Tareen</p>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                tareenmj
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

The second option I tried was making it fixed by changing the class of the navbar, but that messed up the formatting, it looks like:
[image]
As you can see the navbar is completely interfering with everything else.

Any solutions would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is `Engineering` tab a `nav` element ? Or that's a sidebar element ? Need more HTML code.

Comment: Include more of your HTML how is separated that left box from the nav ?  is the nav inside a column ?

Comment: Apologies, I did add enough of the html i feel by now.

Comment: You can use js/jquery to detect scroll position and make the div fixed when scrolled down. And when scroll is at top make its position static.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to do here, you need to update the width and left positioning of the nav-bar, beyond just setting it to position fixed.

For instance you need to get the width of your sidebar and setup something like:

```
.navbar-fixed {
  left: 200px; /* just an estimate of your sidebar's width */
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

You'll also want to add some padding-top to the main-panel, to make sure there's some empty space for the fixed nav to reside in.

```
 .main-panel {
   padding-top: 40px;
 }
```

You'll also need to update these styles for any responsive behavior for your site, but this should at least get you going in the right direction.

Here's a quick demo I made to illustrate: https://codepen.io/scottohara/pen/zwrMbW?editors=1100#

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you have added bootstrap's grids on your side bar and would like to add the same for the nav bar then remove the `container` class from the navbar and apply the grid class on nav tag. Since the navbar is fixed position it will start from the top-left of the screen. so you might want to add other classes like `pull-right` or `col-md-offset-2`.

Thus this way, you have a bootstrap only solution without the need to create separate classes

```
<div class="main-panel">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed col-md-10">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <p class="navbar-brand">Muhammad Tareen</p>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                tareenmj
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important;` to override that class.

Example: `<div style="width:100px !important;">`